# fetch results using join Mysql

Tags: mysql

MY USERID IS 1

```
TABLE users
USERID     NAMES     EMAIL 
1          KAT       1@1.com
2          JOHN      2@2.com
3          FIK       3@3.com


TABLE comunity
COMUNITY_ID  USERID                 MYFANS
1            1#FROM TABLE USERS     1@1.com
2            2#FROM TABLE USERS     1@2.com
3            3#FROM TABLE USERS     1@3.com


SELECT u.USERID, u.NAME FROM  
users u 
INNER JOIN comunity c ON u.USERID = c.USERID
WHERE c. MYFANS = '1@1.com'
```

with his example i only get users which have my email in column MYFANS. but i want to get also users which i have their emails in MYFANS Column
its like select myfans where my email is '1@1.com' and these emails which i have in myfans where my userid = '1'

Comment: What will be expected output as per the given sample data

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya i will get people who have my email in myfan column and also get these which i have their emails in myfan column where my userid = 1 from comunity table

Comment: try this WHERE c. MYFANS = '1@1.com' OR u.EMAIL = '1@1.com'

Comment: thanks @somsgod it works. but the problem it counts COMUNITY_ID in table comunity where my email is 1@1.com and brings my own email according to the COMUNITY_ID which i have their emails. but not these people which i have their emails like i dont get their emails i only get counts of theirs emails and that count brings my email. not thiers. its like it works but i get my own email instead thiers