# Mysql join 2 table with multiple where clause

Tags: mysql

am covering my recently post 
[fetch results using join Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52909571/fetch-results-using-join-mysql)

i made some tries. on wat i want

```
TABLE users
USERID     NAMES     EMAIL 
1          KAT       1@1.com
2          JOHN      2@1.com
3          FIK       3@1.com
4          PET       4@1.com
5          COW       5@1.com


TABLE comunity
COMUNITY_ID  USERID                       FANS
1            1 KAT  #FROM TABLE USERS     3@1.com # FIK IS MY FAN
2            2 JOHN #FROM TABLE USERS     1@1.com # AM FAN OF JOHN
3            1 KAT  #FROM TABLE USERS     5@1.com # COW IS MY FAN
4            4 PET  #FROM TABLE USERS     1@1.com # AM FAN OF PET
5            1 KAT  #FROM TABLE USERS     2@1.com # JOHN IS MY FAN
```

i want to get all fans which have my email in fans column 
i get them like this - this works

```
SELECT * FROM  
users u 
INNER JOIN comunity c ON u.USERID = c.USERID
WHERE c.FANS = 'MY USERID - 1'
```

now the problem is here

i want to also get users which i have they emails to fans column
i did it like this
select fans where my userid = '1'

so i need some correction here

```
SELECT * FROM  
users u 
INNER JOIN comunity c ON u.USERID = c.USERID
WHERE c.FANS = 'MY USERID - 1' 
AND * IN(SELECT c.FANS FROM comunity WHERE c.USERID = 'MY USERID - 1");
```

Comment: Just conforming about your query that You want Jhon as the output of the second query. Right?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Query:

```
SELECT * from
(
SELECT * from community where USERID=1 OR FANS='1@1.com'
) c
left join
users u
ON u.USERID = c.USERID;
```

Comment: thanks @Nilesh tho it has still failed to work. but i will sort this using the programming language i use

Comment: Hello @mike Just conforming about your query that You want all the rows in the example as the output of the second query. Right? As in the, all the rows CAT is either in a fan or in USERID.